# Facebook applicationAuthication Error

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

when i try to open my application
http://apps.facebook.com/allmyfrnds/allmyfriends.php
i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::getSession() in E:\HostingSpaces\bombil\bombil.com\wwwroot\allmyfrnds\allmyfriends.php on line 14
```

MY CODE IS:

```
<?php  

   include_once ("src/facebook.php");  
   $app_id = '160888120643482';  
   $application_secret = 'bbae7def492082fa361da46185852e55';  

   $facebook = new Facebook(array(  
  'appId'  => $app_id,  
  'secret' => $application_secret,  
  'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support  
));  

    if ($facebook->getSession()) {  
    $user = $facebook->getUser();  
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();  
    $me = $facebook->api('/me/friends');  
    //echo "Total friends".sizeof($me['data'])."";  

    echo " <a href=\"http://www.bombil.com/\" target=\"_blank\" >Application Developed By Bombil Media</a> <br>";  
    foreach($me['data'] as $frns)  
    {  
    echo "<img src=\"https://graph.facebook.com/".$frns['id']."/picture\"" . "title=\"".$frns['name']."\"/".">";  

}  

    //echo " 

    //By <a href="\"http://facebook.com/nirbhay.singh\""><img src="\"https://graph.facebook.com/1147530774/picture\"" title="\"nirbhaysingh\"/"></a>";  

    }  
    else {  
    $loginUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&display=page&client_id=160888120643482
    &redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/CANVAS URL/ 
    &scope=user_photos";  
    echo '<fb:redirect url="' . $loginUrl . '"></fb:redirect>';  
}  

?>
```

But When i make upload this code

```
<?php  

   include_once ("src/facebook.php");  
   $app_id = '160888120643482';  
   $application_secret = 'bbae7def492082fa361da46185852e55';  

   $facebook = new Facebook(array(  
  'appId'  => $app_id,  
  'secret' => $application_secret,  
  'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support  
));  

    //if ($facebook->getSession()) {  
    $user = $facebook->getUser();  
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();  
    $me = $facebook->api('/me/friends');  
    //echo "Total friends".sizeof($me['data'])."";  

    echo " <a href=\"http://www.bombil.com/\" target=\"_blank\" >Application Developed By Bombil Media</a> <br>";  
    foreach($me['data'] as $frns)  
    {  
    echo "<img src=\"https://graph.facebook.com/".$frns['id']."/picture\"" . "title=\"".$frns['name']."\"/".">";  

}  

    //echo " 

    //By <a href="\"http://facebook.com/nirbhay.singh\""><img src="\"https://graph.facebook.com/1147530774/picture\"" title="\"nirbhaysingh\"/"></a>";  

    //}  
    //else {  
    //$loginUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&display=page&client_id=160888120643482
    //&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/CANVAS URL/ 
    //&scope=user_photos";  
    //echo '<fb:redirect url="' . $loginUrl . '"></fb:redirect>';  
//}  

?>
```

I GET THIS ERROR:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in E:\HostingSpaces\bombil\bombil.com\wwwroot\allmyfrnds\src\base_facebook.php on line 988
```

PLEASE HELP....I SHALL BE HIGHLY THANK FULL PLS

Comment: is the file "facebook.php" included correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in E:\HostingSpaces\bombil\bombil.com\wwwroot\allmyfrnds\src\base_facebook.php on line 988
```

for this problem surround your code with try { } catch statement.

Edit: Something like this

Probably the path in the include_once is incorrect.That is why you get the first error. Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) for more help.

```
<?php  
   include_once ("src/facebook.php");  
   $app_id = '160888120643482';  
   $application_secret = 'bbae7def492082fa361da46185852e55';  

  try {
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(  
     'appId'  => $app_id,  
     'secret' => $application_secret,  
     'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support  
    ));  

   if ($facebook->getSession()) {  
     $user = $facebook->getUser();  
     $uid = $facebook->getUser();  
     $me = $facebook->api('/me/friends');  
     //echo "Total friends".sizeof($me['data'])."";  

    echo " <a href=\"http://www.bombil.com/\" target=\"_blank\" >Application Developed By   Bombil Media</a> <br>";  
    foreach($me['data'] as $frns)  
    {  
      echo "<img src=\"https://graph.facebook.com/".$frns['id']."/picture\"" . "title=\"".$frns['name']."\"/".">"; 
    }
   }  
 } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      //echo "Error:" . print_r($e, true);
 }
?>
```

Comment: @alex.Thank u for the response sir but i checked the path in include_once but it doesn't help and when i used your code i got this error Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::getSession() in E:\HostingSpaces\bombil\bombil.com\wwwroot\allmyfrnds\allmyfriends.php on line 13 and my facebook.php page host directory is /bombil.com/wwwroot/allmyfrnds on the server.Please Help.

Comment: I think you are using the most recent Facebook PHP SDK, which doesn't have a Facebook:getSession() function.

You'll need to revert to an older 2.x version of the SDK. https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/zipball/v2.1.2

Comment: Try using the 3.0 version. This is the example corresponding to the new PHP SDK. https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

Comment: @alex:Yes alex i figured that out.But after making the required changes on the server and when i tried loading the application i get this error  Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 60: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed thrown in E:\HostingSpaces\bombil\bombil.com\wwwroot\allmyfrnds\src\facebook.php on line 589, why is this error coming

Comment: By adding the following two options to the default $CURL_OPTS, the problem goes away.
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2

Comment: @alex:Thanks dude....but not i am facing another problem....The application is working very fine with my login but when someone else tries to access my application it shows a blank screen with the facebook canvas.

Comment: Did you deployed the application? Did you configured the application correctly?

Comment: @alex- I have configured it correctly but what do u mean by deployed.When i click on sumbit app on the app management page it shows it can be submitted only after it has 10 monthly users

Comment: @alex: snapshots of my configuration pages are here https://docs.google.com/a/bombil.com/?tab=mo#query/vr?view=0&filter=images&hidden=1

Comment: I can't see the snapshots. But is the application on a public server or is it only on localhost?

Comment: yes....now i made some changes in the code the new code is again working fine in my login(i logged in from many different computers) but dosen't work for anyone elses login.my app link is apps.facebook.com/allmyfrnds and the new code is

Comment: <?php  
   
include_once ("src/facebook.php");  
   $app_id = '160888120643482';  
   $application_secret = 'bbae7def492082fa361da46185852e55';  
 try {
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(  
     'appId'  => $app_id,  
     'secret' => $application_secret,  
     'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support  
    ));  
 $me = $facebook->api('/me/friends');  

if ($me) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
  
   if ($facebook->getSession()) {  
   
$user = $facebook->getUser();  
echo $user;
     $uid = $facebook->getUser();

Comment: echo "Total friends".sizeof($me['data'])."";  

    //echo " <a href=\"http://www.bombil.com/\" target=\"_blank\" >Application Developed By Bombil Media</a> <br>";  
    foreach($me['data'] as $frns)  
    {  
echo $frns['sex'];      
echo "<img src=\"https://graph.facebook.com/".$frns['id']."/picture\"" . "title=\"".$frns['name']."\"/".">"; 
    }
   }  
 } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      echo "Error:" . print_r($e, true);
 }
?>

Comment: and the error given is :Error:FacebookApiException Object ( [result:protected] => Array ( [error] => Array ( [type] => OAuthException [message] => An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. ) ) [message:protected] => An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. [string:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] =>

Comment: E:\HostingSpaces\bombil\bombil.com\wwwroot\allmyfrnds\src\facebook.php [line:protected] => 523 [trace:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [function] => _graph [class] => Facebook [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => /me/friends ) ) [1] => Array ( [file] =>

Comment: E:\HostingSpaces\bombil\bombil.com\wwwroot\allmyfrnds\src\facebook.php [line] => 472 [function] => call_user_func_array [args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Facebook Object ( [appId:protected] => 160888120643482 [apiSecret:protected] => bbae7def492082fa361da46185852e55 [session:protected] => [signedRequest:protected] => Array ( [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256 [issued_at] => 1308746819 [user] => Array ( [country] => in [locale] => en_US [age] => Array ( [min] => 18 [max] => 20 ) ) )

Comment: [sessionLoaded:protected] => 1 [cookieSupport:protected] => 1 [baseDomain:protected] => [fileUploadSupport:protected] => ) [1] => _graph ) [1] => Array ( [0] => /me/friends ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [file] => E:\HostingSpaces\bombil\bombil.com\wwwroot\allmyfrnds\allmyfriends.php [line] => 19 [function] => api [class] => Facebook [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => /me/friends ) ) ) )

Comment: @alex:please revert back soon...i am stuck with the same program for past 3 days

Answer (score 0):

The code look Ok, the issue is you didnt login to retrieve the data.
Before opening this page make sure you login with your code in same page or other pages.
For quick verification, you just login with facebook.com first and try this page it should work.

The access token you need to get after successful login.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux server, then make sure the path is correct, also make sure file name is correct even for case sensitivity

```
include_once ("src/facebook.php");
```